# Can't get custom .dll get to work with Quake 2 Rerelease

Tags: dll, crash, steam, quake, quake2

this is a long shot, but I'm having a strange problem. I was compiling the Q2R source code (https://github.com/id-Software/quake2-rerelease-dll) with no issues, but when I replace the original .dll file with it, the game crashes at startup, saying the game .dll wasn't found.

Okay, well, the github page recommended to put all the source in a seperate mod folder and start the game with the mod. I backed up the original .dll back, did it, compiled the project again, started the mod, and it worked!

...until I noticed that the mod uses the vanilla .dll, and not the compiled one. Means, any changes (like a shotgun with ludicrous damage) were not in the game. And yes, I am sure I actually started a mod (the saved games of the vanilla versions weren't there and the game console was activly searching in the mod folder).

Okay, you might say, are you compiling the .dll somehow wrong? That was my thought! Until I found a .dll on moddb.com (https://www.moddb.com/games/quake-2/downloads/berserker-fix-quake-2-rerelease-no-jump), were players were very happy over the change. I tried the provided .dll and... it crashed, like mine in the beginning.

Guys, what am I doing wrong here?

OS: Windows 11, Nvidia 2060 RTX, 16 GB RAM
Using the Steam version of Q2R

Tried different compile configurations, like the used C++ and C version, different Visual Studio versions. None of it worked.

Comment: You can find some of the most knowledgable Quake2 devs on the planet, including Paril, who worked extensively on the re-release, in the Quetoo Discord: https://discord.gg/tpUcRNnu3X